# How to get values of multiple cells in geo raster in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, raster, oracle-spatial

I use SDO_GEORASTER to store raster data in Oracle DB. I have stored the elevation data in georaster table named **DEM_RASTER_6**. And I want to find the elevation of a cell when the location (latitude and longitude) of that cell is given as input.

I used the below SQL query to do it for the locations (139.6532351, 35.646544), (137.15862129082493, 35.08569941846463) and (130.40386925062816, 33.597688116260485) and it worked well using **sdo_geor.getcellvalue** function.

```
SELECT
sdo_geor.getcellvalue(
raster,
0,sdo_geometry(2001, 4326
--,sdo_point_type( 139.6532351, 35.646544, NULL)
,sdo_point_type( 137.15862129082493, 35.08569941846463, NULL)
--,sdo_point_type( 130.40386925062816, 33.597688116260485, NULL)
,NULL, NULL),
1) dem_value
FROM DEM_RASTER_6 a
where
 sdo_anyinteract( a.raster.SPATIALEXTENT,
   sdo_geometry(2001, 4326
     -- ,sdo_point_type( 139.6532351, 35.646544, NULL),
     --  ,sdo_point_type( 130.40386925062816, 33.597688116260485, NULL),
     ,sdo_point_type( 137.15862129082493, 35.08569941846463, NULL),
   NULL, NULL)
 ) = 'TRUE' ;
```

The above query works only for a single point at a time. Now my question is that if we need to find cell values at **multiple points simultaneuosly**, then can we use **sdo_geor.getcellvalues**() function?

For that I tried the below SQL

```
 SELECT
sdo_geor.getcellvalues( 
        raster
        , 0
        , sdo_geometry(
        2005
        ,4326
        ,NULL
        ,SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1,3)
        ,SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(130.40386925062816, 33.597688116260485, 139.6532351, 35.646544, 137.15862129082493, 35.08569941846463)
        ),
        1) dem_value
FROM DEM_RASTER_6 a
  where
 sdo_anyinteract( a.raster.SPATIALEXTENT,
  sdo_geometry(
        2005--multipoint
        ,4326
        ,NULL
        ,SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1,3)--multipoint with 3 points
        ,SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(130.40386925062816, 33.597688116260485, 139.6532351, 35.646544, 137.15862129082493, 35.08569941846463)-- 3 sets of coor for multipoints
        )
 ) = 'TRUE' ;
```

I got the error: , but I get the error ORA-13415: invalid or out of scope point specification ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_GEOR_INT", line 7965 ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_GEOR", line 3311 13415. 00000 - "invalid or out of scope point specification" *Cause: The point position specified by the <ptGeom, layerNumber> or <rowNumber, colNumber, bandNumber> parameter combination was invalid or out of scope. *Action: Ensure that the parameters specify a valid point that is or can be translated into a cell position inside the cell space of the GeoRaster object.

Is the way I use sdo_geor.getcellvalues() wrong or is there another function I can use?

Comment: This is bug 31184230. Patches are available for 19.6, 19.8, 19.9, 19.10. Versions 19.11 and later include the fix. Contact Oracle Support to obtain the patch, or upgrade to 19.11 or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bug 31184230. Patches are available for 19.6, 19.8, 19.9, 19.10. Versions 19.11 and later include the fix. Contact Oracle Support to obtain the patches, or upgrade to 19.11 or later.